# Different color in top and bottom of the surface in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graphics, 3d, matlab-figure

I want to plot a function in Matlab, but with a different color on top and bottom of the surface. My code is:

```
close all;
clear all;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(-10:.45:10,-10:.45:10)
x=X(1,:)'; %'
y=Y(:,1);
N=length(x(:,1))
f = -1.*ones(size(X));

for i = 1:N
    for j=1:N
        if (x(i)~=0 && y(j)~=0) 
            f(i,j) = (x(i).^2- y(j).^2)./(x(i).^2+y(j).^2);
        end
    end
end
figure(1)
surf(X,Y,f, 'FaceColor','white','EdgeColor','blue', 'LineWidth',.5)
view(-61,41)
title('Funktion f(x,y)', 'FontSize',12)
xlabel('x','FontSize',12)
ylabel('y', 'FontSize',12)
grid off
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdMDX.jpg]

This example illustrates what I am after in terms of different top/bottom color (however, it was done with gnuplot):

[image: gnuplot example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not exactly what you want, but it may help:

```
h = surf(X,Y,f, 'FaceColor','blue','EdgeColor','none'); %// no edges
lightangle(-30, 80) %// change values as needed
set(h,'DiffuseStrength',.9) %// change value as needed
set(h,'AmbientStrength',.3) %// change value as needed
```

[image]

As you see, in this type of representation the edges are not shown; rather, the function shape is revealed by the faces' colors. As a result, it may be better (if that's possible in your problem) to use finer sampling. Of course, since 0 is a problematic value for your function, it should be avoided, as your original sampling does (`linspace` with an even number of points also achieves that). For example, with

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(linspace(-10,10,500),linspace(-10,10,500));
```

you get the better looking picture

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. But is that possible with the meshing, exactly in GNUplot?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used GNUplot. To keep the meshing in Matlab, change first line to something like `h = surf(X,Y,f, 'FaceColor','blue','EdgeColor','black');`